# `gnome-text-editor` highlight all occurrences of selected text

Tags: gnome, gnome-text-editor

Previously I was using `gedit` for simple editing tasks. Starting with Ubuntu 22.10 `gedit` was replaced with `gnome-text-editor`.

In `gedit` I could easily see all matching occurrences of the currently selected text, because the editor was highlighting all such text automatically in the currently edited file contents. This is very valuable in code editing and it was provided by the **Quick Highlight** "plugin".

It seems that `gnome-text-editor` does not have this feature. I have to do a text search to highlight all occurrences of a specific text.

Is there a method (hidden configuration change, add-on, etc.) that will add the above-mentioned feature to `gnome-text-editor`?

Comment: I am not sure what it is you want to restore. You are using a different editor with it seems does not have this feature. The question maybe should be how to add this feature to this editor?

Comment: Since `gnome-text-editor` is a replacement for `gedit`, it is expected that it replicates `gedit` by adding extra features or working in a "better way", and not in an inferior way.  I rephrased my question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report or a feature request may be in order.

Comment: OK, then: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor/-/issues/497